# P-value of LR test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, p-value, likelihood-ratio

I've been studying more about GLRT (Generalized Likelihood Ratio Tests) and I came up with the following problem.

Let $X\sim N(\theta,1)$ and consider the hypothesis $H_0:\theta\in[a,b]$ against $H_1:\theta\notin[a,b]$ with $a<b$. What would be the p-value with respect to the class of GLRT tests if we observe $x>b$?

I only found examples for null hypothesis of the type $\theta=c$, that's why I'm confused how I could do this with an interval.

Any help on how to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: A good set of search keywords is "composite hypothesis likelihood ratio".  You won't find much written about that here on CV, so try the Web and the better textbooks.  Wilks' Theorem (for nested composite hypotheses) is relevant.

Comment: Hi! did you manage to figure this out?